# How to reclassify and merge multiple columns of a dataframe according to the colnames classification in another dataframe using R?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, one containing multiple columns of the different classifications (df1) and the other containg the colname classification (df2).

```
df1
          TP53 PIK3CA  PTEN   NF1 SMAD4 ERBB3
X1800018 FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
X1800021  TRUE   TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
X1800026 FALSE  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
X1800027  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
X1800028 FALSE   TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
X1800029  TRUE   TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

df2
      Gene Pathway
1    ERBB3       A
2      NF1       A
3   PIK3CA       B
4     PTEN       B
5    SMAD4       C
6     TP53       D
```

I want to reclassify and merge the df1 columns of the same classification according to df2.

```
df3
                 D      B     A     C     
    X1800018 FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
    X1800021  TRUE   TRUE  TRUE FALSE
    X1800026 FALSE   TRUE FALSE FALSE
    X1800027  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE FALSE
    X1800028 FALSE   TRUE FALSE FALSE
    X1800029  TRUE   TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

**data**

```
df1

structure(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE
), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("X1800018", "X1800021", 
"X1800026", "X1800027", "X1800028", "X1800029"), c("TP53", "PIK3CA", 
"PTEN", "NF1", "SMAD4", "ERBB3")))

df2

structure(list(Gene = c("ERBB3", "NF1", "PIK3CA", "PTEN", "SMAD4", 
"TP53"), Pathway = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", 
"D")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transpose df1, merge with df2, group by pathway, transpose back

```
df1=data.frame(t(df1))
df1$Gene=rownames(df1)

df3=merge(df1,df2,by="Gene",how="all.x")
df3=do.call(rbind,by(subset(df3,select=-c(Gene,Pathway)),list(df3$Pathway),colSums))
df3=ifelse(df3>0,T,F)

t(df3)
             A     B     C     D
X1800018 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
X1800021  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
X1800026 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
X1800027  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
X1800028 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
X1800029 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Turn `df1` into `data.frame` and transform it to long format. Then join it with `df2` and transform result to wider format with aggregating fuction `any`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rowname) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("name" = "Gene")) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = rowname,
    names_from = Pathway,
    values_from = value,
    values_fn = any
  )
```

If you want to turn column `rowname` into rownames add at the end of pipline `column_to_rownames("rowname")`.